# Can we connect SQL Server with Azure notification hub?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-notificationhub

I have connected to Azure notification hub with mobile devices.

Now my task is to trigger messages from SQL Server to Azure notification hub, so that messages will be sent to mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

I would create an Azure Logic App that allows you to link an SQL Server table as a trigger. You can then go down the root of having another trigger (Azure Function for instance) that triggers the notification hub. You may find a connector for that by the way.